# Excel formula SUMIFS use cell value in array range

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I am using a `SUMIFS` formula in an excel document, and one part of the formula is an array to check if one value meets a number of criteria. However the data in the array is typed out manually, eg `{"Nike", "Amazon"}`, however I would like to use a cell value instead of the exact string, i.e. `{$K$3, $K$4}` but excel does not allow that.

The formula I am using at the moment is as follows:

```
=SUM(SUMIFS(INDIRECT(C$2&"[Allocation per Account]"),INDIRECT(C$2&"[Team]"),$J$3,INDIRECT(C$2&"[Role]"),$B3,INDIRECT(C$2&"[Account]"),{"Nike","Thirdbridge","Amazon","EIB","Smith & Nephew","ARUP"}))
```

Where by the match of the table range `[Account]` is set by typing out each value separately.

I have even tried using `INDIRECT` to print the strings, `{INDIRECT($K$3), INDIRECT($K$4)}` alas to no avail.

Is there a way to change these values to cell references?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`{"Nike","Thirdbridge","Amazon","EIB","Smith & Nephew","ARUP"}` is an array literal for a row vector.

So if the values (strings in that case) would be in one row, `K3:P3` for example, then `K3:P3` would be exactly the same row vector.

But if the values are in one column, `K3:K8` for example, then `TRANSPOSE(K3:K8)` will be exactly the same row vector.

`TRANSPOSE` will only work in array context. So you have to input your formula as an array formula:

```
{=SUM(SUMIFS(...,TRANSPOSE($K$3:$K$8)))}
```

To input an array formula put it into the cell withot the curly brackets. Then press [Ctrl]+[Shift]+[Enter] to confirm. The curly brackets should then appear automatically.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, what would be the correct usage of `TRANSPOSE` in this formula, as `TRANSPOSE($K$3:$K$8)` in place of `{"Nike", "Thirdbridge"}` etc just returns the first value as the only value when evaluating the formula, in this case Nike.

Comment: Ah put the whole thing as an array formula with CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER. Works thanks.